# Android ListView Multiple Columns from an Array

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a list view with following row template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- row.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/android_btn_large" android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtLeftButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLeftButton"
            android:text="Riverside Park" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:id="@id/imgLeftButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txtLeftButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:src="@drawable/plus_icon_480">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/android_btn_large" android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtRightButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgRightButton"
            android:text="Riverside Park" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:id="@id/imgRightButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txtRightButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:src="@drawable/plus_icon_480">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the data is stored in a **List** as...

```
List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
rows.add(new String[] { "id", "name" });
```

I want to know what Adapter I should use to fill the ListView with these rows assuming I need 2 column data in a single row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the ListViewAdapter interface in a class and inflate the row-xml in the getView-method. You can use a regular activity with a simple LinearLayout and a list view in it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a SimpleAdapter with a list of HashMap

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("id", "1");
map.put("name", "bob");
mylist.add(map);

//Each row is a new hashmap
map = new HashMap<String, String>();          
map.put("id", "2");
map.put("name", "sally");
mylist.add(map);

//ect...

mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.listrow,
            new String[] {"id", "name"}, new int[] {R.id.txtID, R.id.txtName});
list.setAdapter(mSchedule)
```

Comment: I meant 2 rows from rows collection must be filled in a single ListView row.

Comment: Assume I can't change collection or rows.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the method I posted puts 2 (or more) columns of data in a single row